# Basis and complementary subspace for W...

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis and a complement for:
$$
W =  \left\{ (x,y,z) \in R^{3} : x-2y+4z = 0\right\} \\
$$For the basis, I got 3 different points that were in the plane, and by subtraction, I got two vectors that were in the plane, that are L.I:
$$
B_{w} =  \left\{ (-2,-1,0),(2,-1,-1) \right\} 
$$For the complementary subspace, I need to find a set $S$, such that $W \oplus S = V$.
In my head, if $S$ is a plane that contains the origin and has a normal vector different than $W$ plane, their intersection will be a line. If i choose $S$ to be a line that has it's director vector different than any vector in the span of $B$, i'll get their intersection to be just the $(0,0,0)$. For the subspace $S$, I'll choose it basis to be:
$$
B_{s} =  \left\{ (1,-2,4) \right\} 
$$Since $(1,-2,4)$ is the normal vector of the plane $W$.
Therefore, the complementary subspace for $W$ will be $S$, such that:
$$
S =  \left\{ (x,y,z) \in R^{3} : x = \alpha, y = -2\alpha, z = 4\alpha ,  \alpha \in R\right\}
$$
Proof for the complementary subspace $S$:
$$
\alpha(-2,-1,0) + \beta(2,-1,-1) = \gamma(1,-2,4)\\
\alpha(-2,-1,0) + \beta(2,-1,-1) -\gamma(1,-2,4) = 0\\
$$All three vectors here are L.I, the scalars should be 0, and by that we assume
$$
W \cap S =  \left\{ 0 \right\} 
$$Is that correct? I don't know if my approach is good enough, because I always try to visualize things to get all done.
Is there any advice on the procedures that I need to take to complete an exercise like that?

Thanks!

Comment: The plane goes through the origin, so any two non collinear points (except origin) could already serve as your vectors.

Comment: As far as I read it is correct. I don't know what are the points that you have chosen for the original basis, but the rest is correct. However, note that the vector $(1,-2,4)$ of coefficients of the equation that defines the plane $W$ has to be in the complement of $W$, because by definition, if $(x,y,z)$ is a vector in $W$ then $(1,-2,4)\bullet (x,y,z)=x-2y+4z=0$. You might argue using dimensions that since $W\oplus W^\bot=\mathbb{R}^3$, then the dimension of $W^\bot$ must be $1$ and thus only one non-zero vector is enough to construct the basis.

Comment: @Wore that "⊥" indicates the complement of W? and you're assuming that  because: dim(w+s) = 3, and since their intersctions is null, dim(w) = 2, so dim(s) needs to be 1, right?

Comment: @BrunoReis Yes, exactly. But the shortcut here is that is you have the equation of a plane that passes through the origin, the coefficients of the equation will give you a vector in the orthogonal complement.

Comment: Well, though it may seem trivial, to be rigorous, you still have to show that any vector in $\mathbb R^3$ can be written as a sum of vectors from each subspace. That is $W+S=V$.

Comment: Yeah, thats true @Bubububu

Answer (score 1):

Another way of saying this: from x- 4y+ 2z= 0, x= 4y- 2z so any point in the plane is of the form (4y- 2z, y, z) or, in terms of vectors, y<4, 1, 0>+ z<-2, 0, 1> so {<4, 1, 0>, <-2, 0, 1>} is a basis.  You can find a vector perpendicular to those two by taking the [b]cross product[/b] of those two vectors.